# is their any way to loop an if statement if it does not meet a specific requirement

Tags: c#, visual-studio, loops, if-statement

```
        Console.WriteLine("ALL WORDS YOU TYPE MUST BE LOWERCASE UNLESS STATED OTHERWISE, DO 
        YOU UNDERSTAND? \n \n YES | NO \n");
        string answer = "undefined";

        userInput();
        answer = Console.ReadLine();
        userInputDone();


        if (answer == "yes")
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("\nGreat :)\n");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
        } 
        else if (answer == "no")
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("\nTOO BAD\n");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
        }


        Console.WriteLine("What would you lke to do? \n \n PLAY | INSTRUCTIONS");
```

I'm working on a text-based game to get used to C#, how would i go about looping the if statement so that if the user does not type in yes or no it writes "invalid input, try again" and restarts from the first "Console.WriteLine()"

Comment: I do not understand:  The text clearly screams at me, stating that you should input capital letters `" ... YES | NO ... "` - but then you proceed with only checking lower case answers: `"yes"` / `"no"`. I am confused. Why burden the user .... use a `answer = Console.ReadLine().ToLower()` if you want to force  lower case answers ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Do/While Loop`.

```cs
string answer = "undefined";
do
{
  Console.WriteLine("ALL WORDS YOU TYPE MUST BE LOWERCASE UNLESS STATED OTHERWISE, DO YOU UNDERSTAND? \n \n YES | NO \n");
  answer = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
} while (answer != 'yes' && answer != 'no');
```

Comment: and then the user answers  "yEs" - clearly not understanding :)

Comment: @PatrickArtner I use `.ToLower()` to check it.

Comment: im a bit late to replying to this thread but the "ToLower" helped out alot aswell as the "do while" loops

Answer (score 3):

This could be one solution:

```
while( true )
{
    Console.WriteLine( "Your answer?..." );
    var answer = Console.ReadLine();

    if (answer == "yes")
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine("\nGreat :)\n");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
        break;
    } 
    else if (answer == "no")
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine("\nTOO BAD\n");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
        break;
    }    
    else 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("invalid input, try again\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, you are right, the user input must be part of the loop. I have corrected the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `do while` loops: [https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-do-while-loop](http://Read%20about%20it%20here)

So you basically can do

```cs
do {
   // Ask for your input
} while(answer == "no");
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't need another answer, however...

Encapsulate your logic into a method. It's verbose, but you will get all the satisfaction of knowing you wrote a reusable method:

```
private static string GetUserInput()
{
   var acceptableAnswers = new[] { "yes", "y", "no", "n" };

   const string message = "I am Groot? YES | NO";

   Console.WriteLine(message);

   string input;
   while (!acceptableAnswers.Contains(input = Console.ReadLine()?.ToLower()))
   {
      Console.WriteLine("OMG, you had one job... Read the instructions...");
      Console.WriteLine(message);
   }

   return input;
}
```

**Usage**

```
string answer = GetUserInput();

Console.WriteLine("Game over...");

// do what ever
```

**Output**

```
I am Groot? YES | NO
bob
OMG, you had one job... Read the instructions...
I am Groot? YES | NO
y
Game over..
```